# How to develop a composer app with external lib projects?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

With Symfony 5, I am developing an application, with bundles. Each bundle have its own repository.

In dev (local) environnement, I want my app composer, takes package via symlink, and on production , from git repositories:

```
{
    "type": "path",
    "url": "../common",
    "options": {
        "symlink": true
    }
}, 
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://gitlab.bewizyu.com/XXX/common"
}
```

What the best practice for that?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no best practices around this and any solution that comes to mind seems hacky to me as you would either have to keep 2 composer.jsons or modify the existing one before building for prod. If bundles are used by only this application, consider moving them into the App-namespace instead. Otherwise you probably have to take the bullet and always use repositories or live with the problems/hackiness.

Comment: true, I dont find anything about that, but I am pretty sure this is a common case when developing a Symfony application , right?

Comment: I find it less common with the move towards bundle-less applications. Bundles should only be used to configure libraries. If the code needs to be modified within the application so frequently, that symlinking the library makes sense, it should probably be part of the application instead. Obviously, that is only a general rule and your mileage may vary.

Comment: From SF4 "This is no longer recommended and bundles should only be used to share code and features between multiple applications."

Comment: @ThomasDecaux Just replace the term "bundle" with library and you have something that is compatible with current Symfony versions, but triggers the very same problem

Answer (score -1):

The best practice is to have a local app as similar to production as possible.

Why can't you simply install your bundles from git repositories all the time? You develop a bundle, tag new version and update your main application and you are 100% sure it is the same as production.

With the symlinks, you can face a situation when production crashes and local works because there is a different setup.

Comment: As far as I've been in the same situation, I don't want to tag and release a version of a library that is not ready to be published